# Column names and column order

Tags: r

My data.frame:

```
df
ID Time  a  b  c  d  e
WT    A 28 56 50 60 15
WT    B 54 77 11 67 34
WT    C 53  8 87 62 55
WT    D 30 73 47 82  1
KO    A 24 83 14 17 36
KO    B 91 83 72 41  4
KO    C 79 17 76 21 54
KO    D 41 40 77 49 92
```

I subset and average groups df:

```
use_col=3:ncol(df)
mymean<-aggregate(df[, use_col],by= list(df$ID, df$Time),FUN = function(X)mean(X,na.rm=T))

Group.1 Group.2  a  b  c  d  e
  WT       A    51 52 49 29 47
  KO       A     8 17 78 64 96
  WT       B    79  5 45 83 56
  KO       B    53 47 37 99 17
  WT       C    72 38 56 63 40
  KO       C    51  3 30 47 52
  WT       D     3 30 75 53 73
  KO       D    13 72 16 52 13
```

Why do I loose the first two columns names and how could I keep them?
Also, I try to factor mymean data.frame by:

```
mymean$Group.1=factor(mymean$Group.1, c("WT","KO"))
```

but it does not work. Thank you for the help.

Actually the mean should not have Time and should be like that:

```
mymean<-aggregate(df[, use_col],by= list(df$ID, ),FUN = function(X)mean(X,na.rm=T))
```

However the output is:

```
ID     a     b     c     d    e
KO 75.75 44.25 61.75 52.50 39.0
WT 56.00 57.00 84.25 58.75 39.5
```

But it should be the other way round like this:

```
ID     a     b     c     d    e
WT 56.00 57.00 84.25 58.75 39.5   
KO 75.75 44.25 61.75 52.50 39.0
```

Comment: `by = list(ID = df$ID, Time = df$Time)`  and the first column should already be factored

Comment: Thank you, but still factor does not work

Comment: Then try `mymean$ID <- as.factor(mymean$ID))` after you aggregate

Comment: Hi sorry, still it does not work, just reverse the order from WT KO WT KO to KO WT KO WT.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for with the factoring.  Please expand your question with explanation on the factoring part.  Are you trying to order on the first column?

Comment: maybe it is that: `mymean[order(mymean$ID),]` even tough it is not related with the question. I fear that the solution is not related with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `aggregate()` call, change the `by` argument to have named list elements

```
by = list(ID = df$ID, Time = df$Time)
```

Then for your updated question, you could use

```
use_col = 3:ncol(df)
mymean <- aggregate(df[, use_col], by = list(ID = df$ID), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
mymean[order(mymean$ID, decreasing = TRUE), ]
#   ID     a     b     c     d     e
# 2 WT 41.25 53.50 48.75 67.75 26.25
# 1 KO 58.75 55.75 59.75 32.00 46.50
```

Presumably these values are different from yours because you are using a different data set.

You could also do this with less pain with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
## convert to data table
dt <- as.data.table(df)
## order by decreasing ID
setorderv(dt, "ID", -1L)
## remove the Time column then find the mean of all columns by ID
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), by = ID, .SDcols = use_col]
#    ID     a     b     c     d     e
# 1: WT 41.25 53.50 48.75 67.75 26.25
# 2: KO 58.75 55.75 59.75 32.00 46.50
```

Answer (score 1):

In `aggregate`, another option is the formula method, where we can specify all the non-grouping columns with `.` on the LHS of `~` and the grouping column on the RHS.  As we don't need the 'Time' column in the `mean`, we can use a `subset` of the dataset, get the `mean`, specify the additional arguments `na.rm=TRUE`, `na.action=NULL` (it is to avoid removing an entire row if there is an `NA` element) and `order` the output based on the 'ID' column.

```
  res <-  aggregate(.~ID, subset(df, select=-Time),
                       FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
  res[order(res$ID, decreasing=TRUE),]
  #  ID     a     b     c     d     e
  #2 WT 41.25 53.50 48.75 67.75 26.25
  #1 KO 58.75 55.75 59.75 32.00 46.50
```

---

We could also use `summarise_each` from `dplyr` as another option, where we group by 'ID' column and get the `mean` of all other columns except the the 'Time' and order the output using `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), -Time)  %>%
      arrange(desc(ID))
#  ID     a     b     c     d     e
#1 WT 41.25 53.50 48.75 67.75 26.25
#2 KO 58.75 55.75 59.75 32.00 46.50
```